# Using QGIS project saved in Postgres as project file for QGIS server

Tags: postgresql, qgis

I am trying to set up a Qgis server on debian that uses a Qgis project file stored in a Postgres db.

To get started I followed the official [Qgis Training Module Lesson 12.1](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_server/install.html).
When using a project file stored locally on the server, it works fine.

Now I tried to change the "default qgis project" in the qgis.demo.conf file and indicate my project file stored in the postgres database according to this template :  `postgresql://localhost:5432?sslmode=disable&dbname=mydb&schema=myschema&project=myproject` which I found in the [QGIS User Guide](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/config.html#server-env-variables).

My edited line in the qgis.demo.conf looks like this:

```
SetEnv QGIS_PROJECT_FILE postgresql://localhost:5432?sslmode=disable&dbname=Test&schema=public&project=world
```

When doing a GetCapabilities request I now get:

> "WMS configuration error" There was an error reading the project file or the SLD configuration.

I looked in the qgis.server.log to understand what is going wrong.
"Error, configuration file 'postgresql://localhost:5432?(...)' does not exist"

I am able to access the stored project file with qgis and with pgadmin 4 I can see that it is stored in the database.

Do I indicate the project file wrong?

Comment: were you able to make it working?

Comment: I have a similar issue, I'm able to serve the project file from the server but not able to get it working when I tried to get a saved project from the Postgres database. Do you have any idea what steps are required to set it up correctly? Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you should complete the connectionstring with user and password
SetEnv QGIS_PROJECT_FILE postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432?sslmode=disable&dbname=Test&schema=public&project=world

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community and thank you for your answer. I have a tip for you. It's more pleasant experience to read formatted answers (you can use <pre>, <code> or just insert four spaces before the code/configuration)